# subcaption - How to use 'Figure x' instead of alphabet numbering?

Tags: captions, subcaption

My current table of images looks like:

[image]

However, instead of (a), I'd like the caption to include 'Figure' and continue numbering from previous figures. How would I do this?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Figures
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t!]
      \centering
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Media/Speaker.png}
        \caption{JBL Flip 4 Speaker\\ }
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Media/Meter.png}
        \caption{Dostmann SL328 Sound Level Meter}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Media/test.png}
        \caption{Computer with Bluetooth, Python 3.7.0, and pyaudio module.}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Media/test.png}
        \caption{6}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Media/test.png}
        \caption{4}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Media/test.png}
        \caption{5}
      \end{subfigure}
      \label{fig:test}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you post code with images, you should use the example images of LaTeX: `example-image`, `example-image-a`, `example-image-b`, `example-image-c`, `example-grid-100x100pt`, `example-image-golden`. Or `example-image-duck`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `subfigure`, use a `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption[JBL Flip 4 Speaker]
      {JBL Flip 4 Speaker \\ \\}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption[Dostmann SL328 Sound Level Meter]
      {Dostmann SL328 Sound Level Meter \\}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Computer with Bluetooth, Python 3.7.0, and pyaudio module.}
  \end{minipage}

  \bigskip

  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{6}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{4}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{5}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This way the numbering would be continuous.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the command `\thesubfigure`
and add some formatting details with `\captionsetup`.

See also http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/publishing/latex_captions for more options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Figures
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \arabic{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=period}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t!]
      \centering
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{A1}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{It's a duck}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{C1}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{Here is a duck}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{B2}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{The last duck}
      \end{subfigure}
      \label{fig:test}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]